# Error reading data from MS Access database using RODBC package

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I've got hundreds of individual MS Access files that contain data on individual locations, each with an identical table structure. Rather than creating one database with all these files, they were all save in different folder locations. I'm trying to wrangle the data into one place so it can be more useful and I'm exploring the RODBC package for R to do that.

I'm using the RODBC package in 32 bit Rstudio to access MS Access databases in file locations which I can open and read from. I can establish the file connections and list out all the table objects for each database, but every time I try to query or read one of the tables I get this error:

> [1] "42000 -1907 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s)
>   cannot be read; no read permission on 'HabitatUnits'." [2] "[RODBC]
>   ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM HabitatUnits'"

I experimented another access data base that I created and I was able to read the data no problem, so it must be a restriction imposed on the other data sets. Is there a way to grant access so that R can read in this data without going through each data base to manually change the accessibility?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody or something must have had read permission on the tables before. It is unlikely that each separate table has a unique user.

So the way to grant generic access through RODBC is to identify and use the correct user name and security database. How were the original tables created, by who, and from what?

---

Access 'workgroup security' works almost exactly the same was Windows security works. There are users and groups, which are associated with ID values. And there are permissions, which are associated with ID values, and if you have the correct workgroup file, you can associate permissions with users and groups.

The default user is called 'admin' and has a universal ID value. Any database object which is owned by the ID value can be used by anybody who has a copy of Access installed, because that ID value is universally always the default.

If you create another user, and use that user to create or take ownership of an object and remove the default permission given to the universal 'admin' user and universal 'admins' group and universal 'users' group, then the default user won't have read permission.

An 'admin' password by itself is worthless. The 'admin' user is universal, so you can just use a copy of a system workgroup where the 'admin' password is blank. If someone gives you an 'admin' password, it means either that the password is useless, or that the password is actually for something else (perhaps encryption), or that the password is for someone else - not the 'admin' user, but the other user used for object creation/ownership, for which you need to find the workgroup and username.

---

Access workgroup permissions work the same way as Windows Domain Permissions, but they are not the same thing. They are a completely separate system, devised before Windows had any form of security or authentication or permissions. The list of users is held in a table in a security database (by default, system.mdw). The list of groups is in a table in the same database/file. The list of users that is in each group is in the same database/file. And the ID values associated with each user and group in the same file.

By looking in the hidden system tables of an Access/Jet database, you can see the ID values associated with permissions for the tables and other objects. To match those ID values with names and groups and passwords, you must have the matching security database.

Comment: It looks like most of the files were created by one person and they all have only one user/group ("Admin"). None of the permissions are flagged, so as a test I flagged "read design" and "read data" but I still get the same error. I tried adding uid = "Admin" to the connection line but that didn't change anything either.

Comment: I spoke with the creator and they provided the admin password, but that did not change the error either. They mentioned the old database interface program used a .mdw access file to login.

Comment: Here is a connection string that was used successfully in that program:

dBSourceFile = App.Path & "\StreamHabitatTemplate.mdb"
    sSourceConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" _
                        & dBSourceFile _
                        & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" _
                        & ";User ID=New Admin; " _
                        & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=tenayalake; " & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:System Database= " & App.Path & "\System.mdw" & _
                        ";password=tenayalake"

Comment: There was a "new admin" administrator created to protect the data base such that the default "admin" user could have read permissions the the files. I've tried specifying that user and associated password to no avail. Under" User and Group Permissions" in the access .mdb files, there is only the default "Admin" listed under "Users" and "Current Users". There are no permissions flagged for the default "Admin" user. Under "Groups" there are two names list: "Admins" and "Users" and all permissions are flagged.

Comment: Under the security tab of the file properties there are several groups and users listed including SYSTEM, Administrators (FORFILE1\Administrators), and R1FOR-Everone (AD\R1FOR-Everyone) that all have read, write, and modify permissions as well as a Domain Admins (AD\Domain Admins) user name that has only read & execute and read permissions. How do I specify the correct user so that I can read these files in R??? What information am I missing?

Comment: David, thank you for your continued support in this matter. This is all foreign to me so forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your explanations. I was sent a copy of the system.mdw file that was used to access the data as described above. I looked through the tables in that file and in MSysUserList I found this: Name: admin, Creator, Engine, NEW ADMIN. In the hidden MSysAccounts table I found the same names as well as some passwords and SID's hidden by unusual characters. There is nothing regarding permissions.

Comment: Do I need to associate this system.mdw file with my access database somehow i.e. through the connection code? Or do I need to use the information from the MSysAccounts table? some combination of both? an example or code snippet would be helpful if one exists.

Comment: You have the connection string that associates the database with the user and system database: you commented that above.  An alternative is to use the Access menu or utility to select the correct system database -- Access menus depend on the version of Access.

Comment: The connection string I commented on above was from a previous program used to access the data which is no longer supported. I'm trying to use R Studio and the RODBC package, which as far as I can tell from the documentation does not have arguments for specifying a system database. Is this possible? If so, how? I'd like to avoid using the Access menu since I'd have to do that over 280 times for each separate database.

Comment: @Chris It's probably better to create a new question that isn't confused by all the other stuff. Say "ODBC connection string and/or DSN in R." Give the example of what you've tried so far, and specify that you want ACCESS with a SYSTEM DATABASE. I can't see your connection string and/or DSN, and that's what you need to provide. Probably better in a clearer new question.

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644707/odbc-connection-string-and-or-dsn-in-r?noredirect=1#comment107293442_60644707